# Not enough sugar in strawberry jelly

Tags: jelly

I just made 38 jars of strawberry jelly and realized I did not put all the sugar in recipe. I thought I could scale back until I read the small print on Certgel.

Can I dump it all back in a pot and recook it adding the rest of the sugar, or do I have to throw it all out and restart?

Comment: You probably can, but I'd expect the results to be not ideal (but better than throwing it all out).  Since I'm not definite about this, I'm commenting instead of answering.  My strawberry picking this weekend went much, much faster than I thought, so we wound up with 24 lbs.  Making a lot of freezer jam.

Comment: Best treat it as perishable food while it is in that under-sugared state (unless you have good reason to assume otherwise) - and as perished food if it has been stored in a blatantly unsafe manner...

Comment: It might be okay as it is.  What exactly does the Certgel packaging say that makes you think its no good now?  Also what kind of jelly--- canned, or freezer? And have you frozen/processed it yet?

Comment: What is certgel when it comes to Jelly/Jam? The only certgel I know of is a hand sanitizer.

Comment: I am not sure what Certgel is, but with a regular recipe, you can add the sugar and recook it. I've done it a couple of time when the texture was not right. As specified by @PoloHoleSet, the result will be quite off but it's better than wasting the whole thing.

Comment: "Certain" "gel" - sounds like a fruit pectin (Probably the most well-know US jelly/jam pectin product is called "Sure-Jell") mixture.

Comment: I think the OP means [Certo pectine](https://www.amazon.com/Certo-Premium-Liquid-Pectin-Sure-Jell/dp/B001E560U4). You find all kinds of funny results [searching for 'certgel pectine'](https://www.google.nl/search?q=certgel+pectine)

Answer (score 1):

Your packages of pectin, regardless of brand, has instructions on how to rescue failed jellies and jams. It's been satisfactory for me when I've had to rescue jars I've had fail.

Comment: Is not sweet enough "failed" jelly? I thought that referred to not setting thick enough.

Comment: @Erica, the sugar-acid-pectin balance makes the gelling or "setting" happen. So not enough sugar can make a failed jelly.

Comment: **This does not answer the question**. It only points to *instructions* (which puts it [in another castle](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/225370/your-answer-is-in-another-castle-when-is-an-answer-not-an-answer)), and without actually knowing that these *are* on the package (I doubt that, since the OP 'read the small print')